# BigQuery : unnest 1 table into 2 while preserving refs

Tags: sql, node.js, google-bigquery

I'm currently trying to import BQ tables full of arrays into a third party vizualisation tool that do not support them. I'm more of a node/nosql guy and that BQ step is somehow the complex exception within the project, so I believe I'm not correctly approching the problem to begin with.

A table looks like that:

| Entry ID (primary) | User ID | ...more metadata (finite) | Field ID 1 (dynamic) | Field ID 2 (dynamic) | ...more fields (dynamic) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K1 | U1 | strings & numbers | [Value ID1, Value ID2] | [Value ID5, Value ID6] | ...more arrays of values |
| K2 | U1 | strings & numbers | [Value ID2] | [Value ID5, Value ID6] | ...more arrays of values |
| K3 | U2 | strings & numbers | [Value ID1] | [Value ID4, Value ID6] | ...more arrays of values |

Some more context:

- our system follow a simple pattern: 1 org = 1 dataset = many users
- the datasets are organized the exact same way accross orgs (when it comes to the number of tables and their IDs)
- from now on I'll focus on one given table per org (let's call it "the Data table"): the one shared above
- that Data table only share half of its schema accross orgs (primary key, user id, and some more columns with other metadata, it's finite and known), the second part of the schema (all the "Field .." columns) vary from an org to another (both the number of columns and the column names)
- everything we're discussing will be handled by a node process that iterates over the org datasets, so it must be generic enough to handle all of them
- any intermediary step, like running another pre-process to create intermediary tables or views, is acceptable
- although I used JS notation for arrays, the BQ schema of the "fields" is in string/repeated, but it is possible to alter the way tables are exported to BigQuery if necessary

What I've tried:

- flattening the table by parsing the arrays to string within node the moment those tables are exported to BigQuery => the third party doesn't support custom logic on cells, so in the end, the vizualisation can't correctly interpret the value
- doing everything in the "What I believe I should do" beneath but through Node only: ie by reading BQ, parsing and mapping, then creating the 2 views => it screams inefficiency as I believe Node should only handle the automation part and simply send the query to BQ
- doing that through SQL, but even though I can read it and run simple queries, as soon as I'm trying to mix UNNEST, JOIN and dynamic number of unknown columns, I'm kinda lost

What I believe I should do:

- the third party allows to create Data Model and relations before vizualising, so I could have a view with one row per "values group", and another view that looks like the initial table, except the arrays of values are replaced by a string referencing the "primary key" of that "values group" view

The 2 outputs would look like that:

Refs

| Ref ID | Value 1 (index 0) | Value 2 | Value 3 | ...values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ref1 | Value ID1 | Value ID2 |  |  |
| Ref2 | Value ID5 | Value ID6 |  |  |
| Ref3 | Value ID2 |  |  |  |
| Ref4 | Value ID1 |  |  |  |
| Ref5 | Value ID4 | Value ID6 |  |  |

Map

| Entry ID (primary) | User ID | ...more metadata (finite) | Field ID 1 (dynamic) | Field ID 2 (dynamic) | ...more fields (dynamic) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K1 | U1 | strings & numbers | Ref1 | Ref2 | ...more refs |
| K2 | U1 | strings & numbers | Ref3 | Ref2 | ...more refs |
| K3 | U2 | strings & numbers | Ref4 | Ref5 | ...more refs |

The questions:

- does it sounds logical (from a data analysis standpoint) and doable (from a BQ query standpoint) ?
- I keep thinking 1 process > 1 read > 2 outputs for efficiency because of Node, but I should actually have one query from Data table to UNNEST into the Refs view, and then, another query from Data & Refs to generate the Map view, right ?
- should I use GENERATE_UUID() to handle the RefID generation or there's something else more suited ?

Thanks for making it so far, I'll gladly take any input at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You want to bring the nested table back to a relation data structure.

This is possible and depending on the requirements a good choice to do.

Please be aware that following query is tested only for a small dataset.

```sql
with tbl as 
(Select "K1" as EntryID ,   "U1" as UserID, "strings & numbers" as metadata,    ["Value ID1", "Value ID2"] as ID1,  ["Value ID5", "Value ID6"] as ID2,
Union all Select    "K2",   "U1",   "strings & numbers",    ["Value ID2"],  ["Value ID5", "Value ID6"],
Union all Select    "K3",   "U2",   "strings & numbers",    ["Value ID1"],  ["Value ID4", "Value ID6"],
),
ref as (
select *, row_number() over (order by ref_name) as ref_id
from (
select distinct format("%T",ID1) as ref_name, 
ID1[safe_offset(0)] as Value1,
ID1[safe_offset(1)] as Value2,
ID1[safe_offset(2)] as Value3,
ID1[safe_offset(3)] as Value4,

 from (select id1 from tbl union all select id2 from tbl)
)
)

Select T.* except(ID1,Id2) #
,A.ref_id as Field_ID1
,B.ref_id as Field_ID2
from tbl T
left join ref A on format("%T",ID1)= A.ref_name
left join ref B on format("%T",ID2)= B.ref_name
```

- First we generate your sample table `tbl`.

### Table `ref`

- The rows `ID1` and `ID2` are combined (`union`)
- The array is converted into string `format("%T",ID1)` in the column `ref_name`
- For each entry of the array, we generate a column `ID1[safe_offset(0)] as Value1`
- The select distinct keeps only unique items
- finally, we create a row_number for a unique reference id
- This is put in `ref` table. However, you should safe this in a table `create or replace table yourdatset.ref_table`

### Table `Map`

- We query the `tbl` table without the array columns
- We convert the array column ID1 to a string and join the reference id from the `ref` table: `format("%T",ID1)= A.ref_name`
- The same has to be done for `ID2`